# не отображается iconLayout заданный через presetStorage.add

Tags: yandex-maps-api

задал свой шаблон метки

```js
ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('sokol#blueMy', {
  iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass([
    '<div class="sdasdasd_sasdasd" style="transform:rotate({{options.rotate}}deg);">',
    '{% include "default#image" %}',
    '</div>'
  ].join('')),
  iconImageHref: 'https://chop-sokol.ru/default/img/tracing_car.png',
  iconImageSize: [32, 36],
  iconImageOffset: [-5, -38],
  iconRotate: 0,
  iconShape: {
    type: 'Circle',
    // Круг описывается в виде центра и радиуса
    coordinates: [0, 0],
    radius: 25
  }
});
```

далее создаю карту с кластеризацией и в переменную points передаю json, приведённый ниже, и иконки не отображаются, подскажите, в чём дело ???

```js
myMap = new ymaps.Map(html_map, {
                center:   getDataTracking('getpointscarcenter'),
                zoom:     14,
                controls: ['fullscreenControl']
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            }),
            objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
                /* Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию. */
                clusterize: true,
                /* ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор. */
                gridSize: 19,
                clusterDisableClickZoom: true
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

            if (typeof points.features !== 'undefined' && points.features.length) {
                myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
                objectManager.add(points);
            }
```

```js
{"data":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":10599,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[53.31344,34.30412]},"options":{"iconLayout":"sokol#blueMy","iconImageHref":"http:\/\/sokol\/default\/img\/tracing_car.png","iconImageSize":[32,36],"iconRotate":4},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"606 (онлайн)","balloonContentBody":"тест\r\n                        ","balloonContentFooter":"","clusterCaption":"","hintContent":""}},{"type":"Feature","id":96421,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[53.31593,34.29593]},"options":{"iconLayout":"sokol#blueMy","iconImageHref":"http:\/\/sokol\/default\/img\/tracing_car.png","iconImageSize":[32,36],"iconRotate":172},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"621 (онлайн)","balloonContentBody":"тест\r\n                        ","balloonContentFooter":"","clusterCaption":"","hintContent":""}},{"type":"Feature","id":95906,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[53.28645,34.36395]},"options":{"iconLayout":"sokol#blueMy","iconImageHref":"http:\/\/sokol\/default\/img\/tracing_car.png","iconImageSize":[32,36],"iconRotate":332},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"622 (онлайн)","balloonContentBody":"тест\r\n                        ","balloonContentFooter":"","clusterCaption":"","hintContent":""}}]},"success":true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы достать значения из хранилища пресетов нужно использовать метод .get:

```
ymaps.option.presetStorage.get('sokol#blueMy')
```

Так же для objectManager нужно проставить идентификаторы всем features:

```
feature.id = id++;
```

Вот рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/eavy7hkx/1/